# What does the notation $M^{[2]}$ mean with regards to matrices?

Tags: matrices, relations

I am busy studying transitive closures of relations.

The Matrix of the relation, $M_R$ is

$$M_R = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&1\\ 0&1&0 \\ 1&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

As you might know the transitive closure is given by:

$$M_R^* = M_R\vee M_R^{[2]}\vee M_R^{[3]}  $$

How can I find $M_R^{[2]}$ and $M_R^{[3]}$? It is not the same as $M_R \times M_R$ and $M_R \times M_R \times M_R$ right?

Comment: What is $M\vee N$ for matrices ?

Comment: @Julia that's not what the question is asking, but that's what Dietrich was asking because this notation isn't used *everywhere*.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We find $M^{[n]}$ in the same way we would find $M^n$, only we replace addition with $\vee$ and multiplication with $\wedge$.  So, for example: we have
$$
M_R = \pmatrix{
1&0&\color{blue}1\\
\color{red} 0&
\color{red} 1&
\color{purple}0\\
1&1&\color{blue}0
}
$$
So, the entry of $M_R^{[2]}$ in the $\color{red}2$nd row and $\color{blue}3$rd column is given by
$$
(\color{red}0 \wedge \color{blue}1) \vee
(\color{red}1 \wedge \color{blue}0) \vee
(\color{red}0 \wedge \color{blue}0) = 0 
$$
Overall, we compute
$$
M_R^{[2]} = 
\pmatrix{
1&1&1\\
0&1&0\\
1&1&1
}
$$